# Load full view from onClick()

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Im not sure how to load a view from click() event. I do not want a partial view and i need to be able to feed a simple paramter to it:

```
$('#DepartmentsButton').click(function () {
   onDepartmentClick();
});

function onDepartmentClick() {

var self = this;
var selectedId = gridGetSelectedId();

$.ajax({
    url: '/Location/Departments/',
    cache: false,
    type: 'get',
    data: { id: parseInt(selectedId) },
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
    },
    error: function (res) {
    }
});
```

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: i want to be able to go to the URL Location/Departments' and feed it the parameter 'selectedId' when i click the button 'DepartmentsButton'. The above code seems to do nothing when i load it, how do i load a view from a button click?

Comment: try to change type from get to post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that Departments is a Partial View (Strongly recommended)

create a div to load your partial

and JQ:

```
$('#DepartmentsButton').click(function () {
   onDepartmentClick();
});

function onDepartmentClick() {
   $('#divDepartments').load('/Location/Departments/');
};
```

---

**Revision**: user wants to REDIRECT to View (which really means redirect to View's Action (There better be one -- hint hint)

No Div needed

```
$('#DepartmentsButton').click(function () {
   onDepartmentClick();
});

function onDepartmentClick() {
   window.location='/Location/Departments/';
};
```

Comment: @AnthonyViola it would still work... but I would think Partial b/c I wouldnt want _layout. Of course, everybodys requirements are different...

Comment: It does load but within  the current page, i want to load a whole new view from scratch basically...

Comment: huh? what? huh? i dont understand. speak english.

Comment: do you want to change to a different view? like a redirect?

Comment: The above snippet loads the page i want within the page i am on from the #divDepartments. I dont want to do that i want to basically redirect to a different page

Comment: O, thats different. and EZ. check revision to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#DepartmentsButton').click(function () {
   onDepartmentClick();
});
```

When is this function being called?  Just putting the function in code doesn't make it work.  You need to initialize and call this function.

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('#DepartmentsButton').click(function () {
       onDepartmentClick();
    });
});
```

There are several other things wrong as well.

You have success defined with a parameter but it doesn't do anything.  The function itself doesn't exist and the same applies for failure.  You still need to code those functions.

```
success: function (data) {
    //I don't do anything but take up space, put code to execute on data here.
},
```

Comment: HI thanks for the help, it is defined in the right spot if i click the button i can fire alerts, etc...  What i cant do is load a view. So my current page might be Location/Edit i want to click and go to Location/Department

Comment: way to focus on the problem, i havent typed anything into my profile, i only just created it a few minutes ago and so its done so on its own...

Comment: wrong post, wrong window...ugghh.  I'm not trying to be mean here but there's some critical programming concepts you don't yet grasp.  Nothing wrong with that, we were all there once.  What I'm referring to is you call a function that doesn't exist gridGetSelectedID().  You're accepting a JSON response but nothing coded to process it. Sorry to be so brutally honest but it's the only way you're going to know what you need to read up on.

Comment: @Anthony, yes we've all been there. The important thing is to keep trying. The tech world suffers from something much worse than bad programmers -- we all struggle with communication.